# Double Marker in one PlotLegend

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling, marker

I'm trying to produce a plot to compare two approximations which have in common the same parameter alpha.

I wish to get a plot like showed in the picture:
[image: Desired result]

but I cannot combine the markers and width.

Here is my code:

```
pTLow[B_, pT_] := B^2/3*4/15*pT^2;
Bw01 = Table[{x, pLow[0.1, x]}, {x, 0.001, 2, 0.05}];

Bw03 = Table[{x, pLow[0.3, x]}, {x, 0.001, 2, 0.05}];

BTw05 = Table[{x, pTLow[0.5, x]}, {x, 0.001, 2,  0.05}];

BTw07 = Table[{x, pTLow[0.7, x]}, {x, 0.001, 2,  0.05}];

ListPlot[{Bw01, Bw03, Bw05, Bw07},PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, Black, Black},PlotMarkers -> {{"\[EmptyCircle]", 13}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 13}, {\[FilledSquare]", 13}, {"\[EmptySquare]", 13}},PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize->{600, 600}, AspectRatio -> 1,Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, 23],PlotLegends -> {Placed[PointLegend[{"\[Alpha]=1", "\[Alpha]=2"},LegendMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]" "\[EmptyCircle]",20}, {"\[FilledSquare]" "\[EmptySquare]",20}}], {Center,Top}]}]
```

This is the final result:
[image: Final output]

As you can notice, there is a problem with the legend width.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code to produce the initial plot.

Answer (score 2):

```
ListPlot[{Bw01, Bw03, BTw05, BTw07}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"○", 13}, {"●", 13}, {"■", 13}, {"□", 13}}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> {600, 600}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, 23], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[{"α=1", "α=2"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 30}, 
     LegendMarkers -> {{Row[{"●", "○"}, Spacer[5]], 20}, 
        {Row[{"■", "□"}, Spacer[5]],  20}}], {Center, Top}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, change the option value for `PlotLegends` as follows:

```
PlotLegends ->  Placed[PointLegend[ {"", "α = 1", "", "α = 2"}, 
   LegendMarkers -> Thread[{{"●", "○", "■", "□"}, 20}], 
   LegendLayout -> (Grid[ArrayReshape[#, {2, 4}]] &)], {Center, Top}]
```

to get

[image]